# PHP File Upload (form) isn´t working on webserver (local working on XAMPP)

Tags: php

in my Web-Project there´s a file upload form which is only working if I run it on my local XAMPP (Windows) Server. 
As soon as I deploy it on my Web Server (Linux / Plek), the upload does not working anymore and throw the following exeption:

> Notice : Undefined index: formUploadFile in
>   /var/www/vhosts/business-mates.com/httpdocs/mitglied/includes/easyAccounting/4.php
>   on line
>   258

I have already proofed the php settings (max upload size and max post size).
If I do an var_dump from the $_FILES Variable, there´s nothing in, so the file wasn´t uploaded:

```
array(0) { }
```

There´s the form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" id="formUpload" name="formUpload">
        <input type="file" name="formUploadFile" required>
        <label for="ds" >Hiermit willige ich ein, dass die eingegebenen Daten zur Bearbeitung meines Anliegens gespeichert und verarbeitet werden. Folgende Daten werden an die EK Frachtenservice übermittelt: Alle Daten welche im Formular angegeben sind.
            <input type="checkbox" id="ds" name="ds" required>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Antragsformulare hochladen" name="submit" id="send">
    </form>
```

The expected result is, that the file is located / uploaded in $_FILES as well as it is on my local XAMPP-Server.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance
Christian

Comment: XAMPP contains a webserver, so at least your topic is misleading. Anyhow, what are the differences between the two environments? Also, what is the minimal code and necessary steps to reproduce the issue, i.e. a [mcve]? Please, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Have you checked file_uploads in php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RadicalDingos,

that was the issue.

What a fool I am...